# Posting JSON to Django views with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-views

I am trying to post a JSON object from my client side Javascript to my Django View.

I receive a "500 (Internal Server Error)" When attempting to Post. Does this have to do with the CSRF token? And how can I get around this?

**My AJAX**

```
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: '/demo/saved/',
      data: {'data': JSON.stringify(finalSelection)},
      success: function() {
         console.log("Success")
      }
    });
```

**views.py**

```
def show(request):
    data = json.loads(request.POST.get('data', ''))
    context = {
        'data': data
    }
    return render(request, 'bill/saved.html', context )
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('bill/', views.bill_view, name = 'bill-view'),
    path('saved/', views.show, name = 'selected-view'),
]
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming its really the CSRF problem you mentioned, since you didn't post the 500 error output, you can simply add the csrf token to your `data` that is sent in POST request:

```
$.ajax({
...
    data: {
        'data': JSON.stringify(finalSelection),
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
    },
...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when I do that i get a 403 forbidden error. Any ideas?

Comment: @Bell something is raising `PermissionDenied`. Since I don't see anything in your `show` view, there must be something else you didn't share. Maybe it has a decorator? Or you use some middleware that handles permissions?